# Checking to see if a list of lists has equal sized lists

Tags: list, python

I need to validate if my list of list has equally sized lists in python

```
myList1 = [ [1,1] , [1,1]] // This should pass. It has two lists.. both of length 2
myList2 = [ [1,1,1] , [1,1,1], [1,1,1]] // This should pass, It has three lists.. all of length 3
myList3 = [ [1,1] , [1,1], [1,1]] // This should pass, It has three lists.. all of length 2
myList4 = [ [1,1,] , [1,1,1], [1,1,1]] // This should FAIL. It has three list.. one of which is different that the other
```

I could write a loop to iterate over the list and check the size of each sub-list. Is there a more pythonic way to achieve the result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
all(len(i) == len(myList[0]) for i in myList)
```

To avoid incurring the overhead of len(myList[0]) for each item, you can store it in a variable

```
len_first = len(myList[0]) if myList else None
all(len(i) == len_first for i in myList)
```

If you also want to be able to see *why* they aren't all equal

```
from itertools import groupby
groupby(sorted(myList, key=len), key=len)
```

Will group the lists by the lengths so you can easily see the odd one out

Comment: The problem I see here is that (in case the compiler doesn't optimize it) you are calculating the length of list at index 0 n times plus 1 calculate for each other list, that makes 2 * n length calculations.

Comment: @SanSS, The length isn't _calculated_, it's an attribute. You could store it in a variable if you really need a tiny speed boost though. You would then have to special case the case when the list is empty

Comment: Had a little trouble getting this to work, should the argument of `all` be nested in a list? `all([len(i) == len(myList[0]) for i in myList])`

Comment: @FriskyGrub, All the examples in the question are nested lists, but it will work with a list of any objects, as long as they all have a `len`

Answer (score 7):

You could try:

```
test = lambda x: len(set(map(len, x))) == 1

test(myList1) # True
test(myList4) # False
```

Basically, you get the length of each list and make a set from those lengths, if it contains a single element then each list has the same length

Comment: This isn't very efficient in the case that there are different lengths early on in the sequence. You will still needlessly check the remainder of them

Answer (score 3):

```
def equalSizes(*args):
    """
    # This should pass. It has two lists.. both of length 2
    >>> equalSizes([1,1] , [1,1])
    True

    # This should pass, It has three lists.. all of length 3
    >>> equalSizes([1,1,1] , [1,1,1], [1,1,1])
    True

    # This should pass, It has three lists.. all of length 2
    >>> equalSizes([1,1] , [1,1], [1,1])
    True

    # This should FAIL. It has three list.. one of which is different that the other
    >>> equalSizes([1,1,] , [1,1,1], [1,1,1])
    False
    """
    len0 = len(args[0])
    return all(len(x) == len0 for x in args[1:])
```

To test it save it to a file `so.py` and run it like this:

```
$ python -m doctest so.py -v
Trying:
    equalSizes([1,1] , [1,1])
Expecting:
    True
ok
Trying:
    equalSizes([1,1,1] , [1,1,1], [1,1,1])
Expecting:
    True
ok
Trying:
    equalSizes([1,1] , [1,1], [1,1])
Expecting:
    True
ok
Trying:
    equalSizes([1,1,] , [1,1,1], [1,1,1])
Expecting:
    False
ok
```

Comment: I don't see why this deserves a downvote? Maybe using `*args` is not a great idea if the list is large since you will be making a copy). See my answer for a trick to handle the case when `len(args)==0`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a little more data in failure cases, you could do:

```
myList1 = [ [1,1] , [1,1]]
lens = set(itertools.imap(len, myList1))
return len(lens) == 1
# if you have lists of varying length, at least you can get stats about what the different lengths are
```