# content from multiple txt files into single excel file with separate sheets using python

Tags: python, openpyxl

this question is similar to [content from multiple txt files into single excel file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72527193/content-from-multiple-txt-files-into-single-excel-file-using-python).

Can i have those data in separate sheets instead of one sheet ?

If I have for example 3 txt files that looks as follows:
**file1.txt:**

```
a 10
b 20
c 30
```

**file2.txt:**

```
d 40
e 50
f 60
```

**file3.txt:**

```
g 70
h 80
i 90
```

i would like to have file1 as sheet1, file2 as sheet 2 etc in one single workbook. using openpyxl will be much helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is slightly different than my other answer, but the basics are the same. Biggest change is loading the files inside a loop, and naming the sheets...

**requirements.txt**

```
pandas
openpyxl
```

**code**

```py
# we use pandas for easy saving as XSLX
import pandas as pd


filelist = ["file01.txt", "file02.txt", "file03.txt"]


def load_file(filename: str) -> list:
    result = []
    with open(filename) as infile:
        # the split below is OS agnostic and removes EOL characters
        for line in infile.read().splitlines():
            # the split below splits on space character by default
            result.append(line.split())
    return result


with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx") as writer:
    sheet_names = ["sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3"]
    for idx, filename in enumerate(filelist):
        df = pd.DataFrame(load_file(filename))
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_names[idx], index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: testt.py:25: FutureWarning: save is not part of the public API, usage can give unexpected results and will be removed in a future version
  writer.save()

Comment: why do i get header with 1,2,3 ect in all pages

Comment: the header can be removed by using `header=false` and the issue with the `save()` method should be resolved by switching to the more pythonic `with ... as ...` pattern. See updated code above

Comment: also if i have to add dynamically more contents or do arthimteic calulations to sheet2? then which part of code should be edited?

Comment: that really depends on what exactly you want to do. With the current implementation, the `load_file()` function accepts any length of column, if the columns are space delimited. As for arithmetic calculations, I would do that in the dataframe (before the `df.to_excel()` call, or in the sheet itself

Comment: i shall create a new question for adding different header to different page. can you help ?